# Como substituir palavras em uma página inteira

Tags: php

Como eu substituo uma determinada palavra por outra via PHP ?

Tenho um roda pé com a seguinte frase : **Powored by: teste** e gostaria de susbstituir **teste** por **minha empresa**

**Obs :**

> Já usei o **str_replace();** más não funciona pois não esta em uma **$var**

Comment: Tá faltando detalhes ai :P, vc carrega como essa página? o `str_replace()` não faz o serviço corretamente pq?

Comment: Irie arrumar a question, más elas esta em **Html** e gostaria de mudar um "rodapé" está **Powored by: Teste** , por **Powored by: minhaempresa** entendeu mais o menos ?!

Comment: Detalhe, esta frase não se encontra em uma **$ var **

Comment: pra q vc precisa disso ? c vc tem o cod basta achar na programação onde esta o powered by

Comment: @rray  syntax error, unexpected ''index.html'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: $novoHtml = str_replace(file_get_contents('teste', 'minha empresa', 'arquivo.html'));

Comment: @rray Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 3 to be resource, string given in C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\index.php on line 9

Warning: str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 1 given in C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\index.php on line 9

**ESTOU USANDO O SERVER DO PHP, NAO ESTOU TENTANDO ABRIR DIRETO NAO VIU KKK**

Comment: Desculpe inverti os argumentos, agora deve estar certo, lembre de passar o caminho do arquivo se não estiver na mesma pasta, `$novoHtml = str_replace('teste', 'minha empresa', file_get_contents('arquivo.html'));`

Comment: @rray segue os links **->** http://pt-br.tinypic.com/r/2zozxjk/9 **->** http://pt-br.tinypic.com/r/2hn2s6h/9